# Crystal Reports Version

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have an application which was written in Visual Basic 6.0 and some version of Crystal Reports (I believe with a version that came with it). I need to make a few updates to the report now. We have the `.rpt` file.

Is there a way with which version of Crystal Reports that this was created?

Answer (score 4):

Open Crystal Reports and then open the report.

Go to Report - Performance Information.

This will tell you what version of Crystal Reports was used to build the report.

Comment: Thanks Robert! However, my problem is that I seem to be having a lower version of Crystal Reports and hence I am unable to open my report. Is there a way to read the binary `.rpt` file and get the version?

Comment: I'm don't know how to read the version number directly from the file.          

An alternate that may work for you, depending on the version used and if data was saved with the report is to download the free Crystal Report Viewer.          

Open the report file and use: 
 File - Summary Information (Statistics tab) to see the file version number.